# Is this case Active or Passive Voice?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I'm learning English and trying to use Voices. Yesterday i had answered on StackOverflow and typed like below

> This file is located here

I think it's the Passive Voice, but in Russian (my native language is Russian) it's the Active Voice, because it translates as *располагает*СЯ, where *располагает* is like English "*locate*" and **СЯ** is like English "*self*".

Can you tell me what Voice is it in English? Did i use it right?

Comment: Hi Kastaneda! Like the adjectives *bored, interested*, there is also an adjective *located*. The adjective *located* must always take a preposition [*located **on, in, at, here, there*** etc]. Your sentence is correct. Some English adjectives have the same from as past participles of verbs. That means that two different types of sentence can look the same. One type of sentence: *Subject +  'BE' +  Adjective* --> "He was tall". A passive sentence: *Subject + 'BE' + Past Participle* "He was killed". Your sentence is the first type. It *looks* passive because "located" *looks like* a participle!

Comment: In English, the *locate* part is not needed, *is* serves the purpose. What you have is, "This file is right here," *is* = располагает  and *right* = СЯ (Some non-native speakers use the expression "is here itself")

Comment: @Kris, "this file is located here" is my answer for question "where i can read this file?". In this case "this file is right here" is correct?

Comment: Have you visited out sister site [ell.se] yet?

Comment: You probably mean 'not yet.'

Answer (score 4):

In order to interpret this sentence as passive voice, we have to assume there is an agent implied:

> This file is located here *by someone*.

My guess would be that strict followers of Strunk and White would read the sentence like this, but I have my doubts about this interpretation. To *locate* something means that someone establishes the location, not that someone *places* it there.

We can read the sentence also as active, by seeing the past participle *located* being used attributively (used as a kind of adjective). The verb *is* becomes a simple copula in that case.

The sentence can be read in the same way as:

> The file is big.
>   The file is small.

Other participles that can be used attributively are:

> The file is encrypted.
>   The file is lost.
>   The file is saved.
>   The file is corrupted.

Although it *is* possible to read an implied agent in these sentences in some cases (the file may be saved *by John*), it is (almost) senseless to imply an agent in other cases —who cares who or what has *encrypted* a file, or *corrupted* it?

So while it is possible to read your sentence as *passive*, I think the common and sensible interpretation is to read it as an active voice.

Comment: I've just been looking at the participle - adjective continuum grey area. Interestingly, 'The file was located here' (when used with the sense 'The file was [hint of finally] found here') is unarguably a passive usage. WordNet-Farlex are happy with the deverbal adjective: **located** Adj. 1. located - situated in a particular spot or position; "valuable centrally located urban land"; [cf] "strategically placed artillery"; "a house set on a hilltop"; "nicely situated on a quiet riverbank" >> I'd not argue. OP's sentence is certainly not passive; perhaps 'be located' should be considered a MWV.

Comment: Thanks, if it's the active voice, than i had to write _this file locates here_ ?

Comment: Perhaps this is a deponent or semi-deponent usage? OP sure chose a humdinger.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, sorry, can you rephrase your answer? I (and google-translate) don't understand:). And what is "OP"?

Comment: At least one verb in English (be born) can't be replaced directly by an alternative not including 'be'. (Though the French have a single-word verb, 'naître'.) oerkelens and I believe 'This file is located here' doesn't use the verb 'locate' at all, but the corresponding adjective. 'We located [found] the tour guide in the pub' passivises to 'the tour guide was located [= found] in the pub' (which has at least one more meaning – 'the tour guide was located [= based / situated] in the pub'. Adding 'by us' makes the passive usage certain (though 'to locate' can also mean 'to place / position')!

Comment: OP is either 'original post' or (as here) 'original poster'. Kastaneda! And a humdinger is a doozy, one of the most remarkable, demanding and interesting examples possible.

Comment: Thanks:) And as a result - what should i type, when i want to put a link to file? _This file locates here_ or _this file is located here_ or both variants are right?

Comment: _The file locates here_ makes no sense, as it means something like _the file is finding here_. What is the file finding? "The file is located here" is fine. And it is active. There is no reason to change it. It is absolutely okay.

Comment: @oerkelens, thanks, now i understand) But in schoolbook, which i use, the passive voice described like '_someone **to be** verb3_' (where **to be** is am/is/are and verb3 is verb in 3 form, ie verb + ED), and that's why i thought _file is located here_ is the Passive Voice. I will clarify it.

Comment: It's often the passive – that's the way it's formed – but there are other things that look exactly the same.

Comment: @Kastaneda Many schoolbooks contain quite absolute "rules" that are simply not always correct. What is worse, they sometimes copy _wrong rules_ from sources like Strunk&White (espacially when it comes to the passive, Strunk&White made some serious mistakes!)

Comment: If you're telling someone where to replace the file, all Anglophones would say "The file goes here". A formal passive alternative would be "The file is to be / must be replaced here".

Comment: omg, at someday i'll understand it :)

Comment: ... someday, I'll understand it [no 'at'] :) (Probably less than 20% of Anglophones could give even a working definition of the 'passive' construction.)

Comment: And wondering again about the anonymous down-vote :?

Comment: You're at "2" at the moment; was there an enormous downvote? I don't downvote things, but I did wince at your mention of Strunk and White. They don't have anything to say about Passive that's worth reading, let alone following; followers of S&W may be safely ignored, like followers of the Flying Spaghetti Monster.

Comment: Oh, and as to whether it's "passive voice" or not, there is no voice system in English, just as there is no case system, no mood system, and only two tenses. All this phony terminology "Passive Voice", "Subjunctive Mood", "Past Perfect Tense", etc. are imports from Latin and they fit English like a three-dollar suit.

Comment: +1 from me! I think some people just don't like grammar:)

Comment: @JohnLawler: I only mentioned S&W as a possible explanation why some people would see _every_ <subject><be><participle> as a passive construction. I certainly did not mean to promote them, their followers or their ideas! (And indeed, there is just a single downvote, but since it came — as usual — without any comment, I wondered.)